# MySQ: IF() function in JOOQ

Tags: mysql, jooq

I see JOOQ doesn't support MySQL's IF Function, But I find `iif()` in `DSL.java`, it's SQL Sever style, I used it in MySQL, it works well, so can I use iff() in My MySQL query?
It's my test code

```
dslContext.select(EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID,
                DSL.iif(EMPLOYEE.ALGO.eq(1), EMPLOYEE.FULLNAME, EMPLOYEE.ACCOUNT).as("fullname"))
                .from(EMPLOYEE)
                .where(EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID.eq(100)).fetchOneInto(Employee.class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jOOQ 3.14 will add native support for MySQL's `IF()` via [#10160](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10160). This isn't really a necessary feature, it's mere convenience compared to writing the equivalent `CASE` expression:

```sql
-- MySQL
IF (C, A, B)

-- Standard SQL
CASE WHEN C THEN A ELSE B END
```

If you prefer `IF()`, you can always write your own [plain SQL template](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) even before jOOQ 3.14